# Bootstrap-Slider shows Text Boxes instead of slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-slider to create a slider option in my webpage. But it shows only text box instead of slider. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the JSFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/wzndt6La/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/
bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<p>Slider Box</p>
<input id="ex13" type="text" data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400]"
 data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30" 
data-slider-ticks-labels='["$0", "$100", "$200", "$300", "$400"]'/>
```

Comment: bootstrap 2 won't work with jquery 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of libraries is wrong.

Moreover, like you can see in [documentation](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) you missed the ***data-provide*** attribute:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>


<input id="ex13" type="text"
       data-provide="slider"
       data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400]"
       data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30"
       data-slider-ticks-labels='["$0", "$100", "$200", "$300", "$400"]'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

so you need to downgrade your `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js"></script>` to `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and everything works as expected.

```js
$('#ex1').slider({
 formatter: function(value) {
  return 'Current value: ' + value;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.7.2/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
```